# openssl ts command not working - trusted timestamps

Tags: openssl, trusted-timestamp

I'm trying to execute the following command with openssl ts according to the [ts manual](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ts.html)

```
openssl ts -query -data myfile.foobar -cert -out request.tsq
```

Problem: **openssl:Error: 'ts' is an invalid command.**

I can't find any useful instructions on how to install ts for openssl anywhere, so help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.opentsa.org/), that functionality was added in v0.9.9. You can check the version with this command:

```
openssl version
```

Comment: @David: I was rather puzzled by it too.  I even looked in the source code that I built from and could find absolutely no evidence of the ts command.  It turns out I am using 0.9.8p.  I hope you get it working.

Comment: Alright, I tried it and everything worked out fine, thanks! [this is what I did](http://serverfault.com/questions/143582/how-to-update-openssl-using-putty-and-yum-command/220815#220815). Thanks again!